# Why the query is slow + How to check my proc performance and sort out the reason for slow query

Tags: sql-server

This stored procedure needs to be query optimized:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Tenant_Search_getDetail]   
    @guidCorpId uniqueidentifier,
    @guidContext uniqueidentifier,
    @searchText nvarchar(50) = null,
    @searchIndex nvarchar(50) = null,
    @status bit = null
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Tenant_UnitInfo
    --     As
    --     (
    --     select UN_Tn_Guid,UN_GUID,UN_Desc Descrp,UN_CreatedOn CreatedOn,UN_Enabled IsEnabled from UN_UNIT
    --     inner join  Tenants on Tenants.TN_UN_GUID=UN_GUID and Tenants.TN_TN_GUID=UN_Tn_Guid       
    --     )  

    Declare   @guidCorpContext uniqueidentifier = '277475bb-e977-422a-9cd3-b3f0a4a1b94d'   
    Declare   @guidContactContext uniqueidentifier = 'de958a6d-e21e-42af-9fb7-db4dbc9ca1cc'

    ;with Tenants As
    (
     SELECT
         UN_GUID TN_UN_GUID, UN_TN_GUID TN_TN_GUID,
         UN_Desc Descrp, UN_CreatedOn CreatedOn,
         UN_Enabled IsEnabled
     FROM   
         UN_UNIT
     INNER JOIN 
         UR_UnitRelation ON UN_GUID = UR_UN_GUID_From
     WHERE  
         UR_UN_GUID_To = @guidCorpId 
         AND UR_CLSID = @guidContext
         AND (@searchText IS NULL OR 
               (@searchText IS NOT NULL AND UN_Name LIKE @searchText))
         --AND (@searchIndex is null OR
         --     (@searchIndex is not null AND UN_Name like @searchIndex))
         AND (@status IS NULL OR 
                 (@status IS NOT NULL AND UN_Enabled = @status))
    ), 
    Tenant_TenantInfo AS
    ( 
       SELECT 
           TN_Guid, TN_Code, TN_Name, TN_IsActingSystem, 
           RAT_Reference 
       FROM
           TN_Tenant 
       INNER JOIN  
           Tenants ON Tenants.TN_TN_GUID = TN_GUID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
           AT_Attribute ON AT_TN_GUID = TN_GUID 
                        AND AT_Context = '1719c751-f699-435f-b70a-50259c1d48e6'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
           RAT_ReferenceAttribute ON RAT_AT_GUID = AT_GUID  
       WHERE
           @searchText IS NULL OR 
                (@searchText IS NOT NULL AND (TN_Name LIKE @searchText OR 
                                              TN_Code LIKE @searchText ))  
    ), 
    Tenant_CorpInfo AS
    (    
      SELECT 
          UN_TN_GUID CorpTnId, 
          UN_GUID CorpId, UN_NAME CorpName,
          TN_TN_GUID TenantId 
      FROM
          UN_UNIt             
      INNER JOIN 
          UR_UnitRelation ON UR_UN_GUID_From = UN_GUID 
                          AND UR_CLSID = @guidCorpContext  
      INNER JOIN 
          Tenants ON Tenants.TN_TN_GUID = UR_TO_TN_GUID 
                  AND Tenants.TN_UN_GUID = UR_UN_GUID_To    
    ),
    Tenant_ContactInfo AS
    (      
      SELECT  
          CTAT_Phone, CTAT_Email, TN_TN_GUID TenantId 
      FROM
          UN_UNIT     
      INNER JOIN 
          UAR_UnitAttributeRelation ON UAR_UN_GUID = UN_GUID
      INNER JOIN
          Tenants ON Tenants.TN_TN_GUID = UAR_TN_GUID 
                  AND Tenants.TN_UN_GUID = UAR_UN_GUID      
      LEFT JOIN
          AT_Attribute ON UAR_AT_GUID = AT_GUID 
                       AND UAR_Context = @guidContactContext
      LEFT JOIN
          dbo.CTAT_ContactAttribute ON AT_GUID = CTAT_AT_GUID
      WHERE
          (CTAT_Phone is not null) OR (CTAT_Email is not null)    
    ),
    Tenant_ProfileInfo AS
    (     
       SELECT
           AT_TN_GUID ProfileImageTnId, AT_GUID ProfileImageId,
           TN_TN_GUID TenantId 
       FROM
           UAR_UnitAttributeRelation
       INNER JOIN
           Tenants ON Tenants.TN_TN_GUID = UAR_TN_GUID 
       INNER JOIN
           AT_Attribute ON UAR_AT_GUID = AT_GUID 
                        AND UAR_Context = '708ae079-e1a0-440f-9607-895bc73aeec0'
       WHERE 
           AT_Context = '47BE040E-B88D-47D7-810B-315E2720C294'     
    ),
    Tenant_UnitInfo AS
    (
      SELECT
          UN_Tn_Guid, UN_GUID, UN_Desc Descrp, UN_CreatedOn CreatedOn,
          UN_Enabled IsEnabled 
      FROM
          UN_UNIT
      INNER JOIN
          Tenants ON Tenants.TN_UN_GUID = UN_GUID 
                  AND Tenants.TN_TN_GUID = UN_Tn_Guid       
    )      
    SELECT
        TN_Guid, TN_Code, TN_Name, TN_IsActingSystem,
        RAT_Reference, CorpTnId, CorpId, CorpName, 
        CTAT_Phone, CTAT_Email, 
        ProfileImageTnId, ProfileImageId,
        UN_Tn_Guid, UN_GUID, Descrp, CreatedOn, IsEnabled     
    FROM
        Tenant_TenantInfo TENANT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Tenant_ProfileInfo TNPROFILE ON TNPROFILE.TenantId = TENANT.TN_Guid
    --LEFT JOIN Tenant_UnitInfo UNIT ON UNIT.UN_Tn_Guid=TENANT.TN_GUID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Tenant_CorpInfo CORP ON CORP.TenantId = TENANT.TN_Guid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Tenant_ContactInfo CONTACT ON CONTACT.TenantId = CORP.TenantId

RETURN 0
```

I have joined `Tenants` common table expression with most of the other common table expression. Will it decrease performance? How to write the above query to improve performance?

Comment: Where is the "above query"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having several CTE's which can lead to very poor performance in your query, create temporary tables instead and use those in your final query.

Example for your first CTE - Tenants:

```
 SELECT
                UN_GUID TN_UN_GUID,
                UN_TN_GUID TN_TN_GUID,
                UN_Desc Descrp,
                UN_CreatedOn CreatedOn,
                UN_Enabled IsEnabled
INTO #tenants
        FROM    UN_UNIT
        INNER JOIN UR_UnitRelation ON UN_GUID = UR_UN_GUID_From
        WHERE   UR_UN_GUID_To = @guidCorpId AND UR_CLSID = @guidContext
                AND (@searchText is null OR ( @searchText is not null AND UN_Name like @searchText))
                --AND (@searchIndex is null OR ( @searchIndex is not null AND UN_Name like @searchIndex))
                AND (@status is null OR ( @status is not null AND UN_Enabled = @status))
```

Do this for all CTE's and use the temporary tables created this way in your final query.

Comment: Indexing the temp. table can also improve performance. Look at query plan and statistics IO output.

Comment: What @JamesZ sais is correct. In this case though, the performance gain would be from materializing the CTE's to temporary tables. CTE's are generally not materialized by SQL Server. Temporary tables have statistics, which also helps in improving performance. If the performance gain is still not enough, you can indeed add indices to the temporary tables to further improve performance.